# How to launch camera app from my windows 10 app programmatically?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1, windows-10

I am developing a windows 10 app. Please tell me a way to open Camera app from my windows store app.
I know we can use LaunchUriAsync function to open different app which has a registered Uri in registry. But the problem is I don't know what is the registered URI for Microsoft windows default camera app. If anyone knows the camera URI please share with me. Or please tell me a way to open windows store app which has no registered URI.

Comment: So... Your question is "How to get the URI of a default Windows 10 App"?

Comment: yes something like that....and if there is no URI registered for Camera app then how we can open Camera app from our app?

Comment: Why do you want to open the camera app? Do you want to open the camera, take a photo and save it to be able to access to it from your application?

Comment: all I want to do is just open camera app....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opening the camera app can fail for various reasons, and the camera app itself may just throw out an error message if the user's PC doesn't have a camera available (ie, no webcam, etc), so I'd strongly recommend **NOT** doing this. That said...

On Windows 10, at least, the default camera app installs with a protocol URI of `microsoft.windows.camera:`. (You can find installed protocols under `Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Associations`) **Edit: Note, turns out that this protocol isn't registered on windows 8.1, so keep that in mind too!**

You can use the [LaunchUriAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.launchuriasync.aspx) API to call that URI, and that should open the Camera app:

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("microsoft.windows.camera:"));
```

As I said before though, this could fail for a bunch of reasons, so I wouldn't recommend this. I'd recommend using the Camera API and building your own camera controls if you need that functionality, since you can probably test if the user even has a camera to open, with a bit of luck. See the [Camera Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit) we maintain on GitHub if you want an example of that.

Comment: Is there anyway to simulate a camera without having an actual camera? I'm working with UWP but my laptop does not have a camera

Comment: @gayan1991 What do you mean by "simulate"? There must be some peripheral to capture surroundings and that's not something you can "simulate." If a laptop does not have a built-in camera, you want to handle scenarios like when one is connected via USB.

Comment: Not sure why you'd recommend not doing this when you can just catch any potential exceptions. If `LaunchUriAsync` throws any specific exceptions, you can form your error message based on that or check if a peripheral exists beforehand. E.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30809094/how-to-detect-is-a-camera-is-available-using-istypepresent-in-a-windows-10-unive

Comment: @JamesM because when you launch an app through mobile emulator it simulate a camera even though it shows only RGB colors. I was thinking may be there is a desktop version as well

Answer (score 0):

to use the standard camera on back of device:

PhotoCamera camera = new Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera(CameraType.Primary);

but then you catch some event to control the camera...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly but something changed when moving from .net framework to .net core. This Worked for me

```
var ps = new ProcessStartInfo("microsoft.windows.camera:")
            {
                UseShellExecute = true,
                Verb = "open"
            };

Process.Start(ps);
```